# Can't execute .jar files as non-admin user on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, permissions, java

I have multiple computers that I am the administrator for. They have non-admin accounts used by their daily users, and I use my admin privileges to execute programs for those users on occasion.

On one computer, the user cannot execute any .jar files, even when I type my administrator password to execute Java. If I try executing the same .jar file while logged in as my admin account, it works fine. I can also open a CMD window as administrator while logged in as the non-admin user, and call a command line with java, e.g. `java -jar myfile.jar`, and it also runs fine.

How can I get Java working for the non-admin account without having to open a CMD window?

Comment: First thing to try is to uninstall and re-install the JRE.  Something is messed up with the file association in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT or there is a group policy preventing it. I am mostly sure of the cause but not the cure without more information.  Also, one does not "execute" a JAR file.  It is nothing more than a zip file with java classes inside of it.  The java application executes jar files.  It would be like saying you can't execute a word document.  You might already know this but I am making sure.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Yes, I do understand how .jar files work, I was just using a shorthand. I tested changing the other user to an admin account, and it still has the same problem. I also tried uninstalling and reinstalling Java entirely, which didn't fix it.